# Message sent to a ship traveling away at 37.5% light speed?

Tags: space-travel, spaceships, spacetime-dimensions

I have a ship traveling away from Earth at around 37.5 percent of light speed. How long will a message take to reach first Earth, and then a response to reach the ship, both from Earth perspective and from Ship perspective?? Thanks!

Comment: How far away is the ship? How is the message being transmitted? Is the ship accelerating? This needs more details to be answerable.

Comment: In who's time frame?

Comment: Also, this looks like a basic Algebra word problem about one train catching up to another.  (I hated those, and did poorly on them.)

Comment: Are we supposed to correct the wavelength shift too and assume both clocks are already perfectly synchronised?

Comment: At 37.5 c, the gamma factor is about 1.08, meaning each sees the other aging 8% slower. You might as well ignore that for the purposes of the calculation, since it will be nearly negligible w.r.t. the time the of flight for a message. Do it like it was ordinary non-relativistic speeds.

Answer (score 4):

Let $V$ be the ship's velocity

Let $c$ be the speed of light

Let $P_0$ be the position of the Earth.

Let $P_1$ be the position of the vessel when the message is sent.

Let $P_2$ be the position of the vessel when the response is received.

Let $D_{10}$ be a distance between $P_1$ and $P_0$

Let $D_{02}$ be a distance between $P_0$ and $P_2$

Assuming the message travels at the speed of light then

The round trip time will be

$$T_{roundtrip} = T_{10} + T_{delay} + T_{02}$$

where $T_{delay}$ is the time it takes Earth to answer the message after they receive it.

and $T_{10}= \frac{D_{10}}{c}$
and $T_{02} = \frac{D_{10}+V*T_{delay}}{c*(1-V)}$

The velocity $V$ doesn't impact the time it takes for Earth to receive the message but will cause a doppler-shift in the messages transmitted frequency -- in both directions.

Subjectively everyone aboard the spaceship will experience a time dilation of $7.6\%$.

This means when the ship's chronometer reads 92.4% of the actual time of flight for D_{01} then Earth will have received the message.  The delay answering the message and return time of flight are similarly scaled for the ship's chronometer.

Comment: This equation seems intuitively wrong (for example, each second of delay increases distance, so there should be some multiplicative factor there). Confirming with some easy math numbers (initial position 1 light second away from earth, velocity 0.5c, 1 second delay, everything in Earth's frame of reference), the equation gives us 3.5 seconds, but the real number should be 6 seconds (1 second to earth + 1 second delay puts the ship 2 light seconds away when the response goes out, and it takes 4 more seconds for the response to overtake the ship at the 4 light second mark).

Comment: @manveti, you are correct.  I had a mental hiccup assuming an instantaneous response or effectively instantaneous response for the distances involved.  I think I fixed it.

Comment: Almost there. There also needs to be a V * T_{10} component in the distance for the return trip (i.e. s/V * T_{delay}/V * (T_{10} + T_{delay})/).